# Return a single value depending on contents of a variably sized set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm querying for user information from the database. I'm specifically interested in getting data from a field called `CONTENTS`, but only if there is a matching `DESCRIPTION` for a given `USERID`. Additionally, I do not want to return the `CONTENTS`, I instead want to parse through a set of them. The number of rows returned can be variable, from 0 to a very large amount. The `CONTENTS` field is always going to be either one character or no characters. Depending on if a certain character is found in the set, I will return different values. No, a `WHERE` clause does not help here, since I want only one result, regardless of number of rows returned.

- If there is data in the set:

  - If the data contains characters other than `N`, space, or blank, return `*`
  - Else: return `X`
- Else: return `_`

I have a working query for this, but it's massive and copies similar segments of SQL multiple times within it:

```
IF(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE USERID = '123456789'
    AND DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')
    AND CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ')
    ) > 0
    SELECT '*'
ELSE
IF(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE USERID = '123456798'
    AND DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')
    ) > 0
    SELECT 'X'
ELSE
    SELECT '_'
```

As you can see, I'm copying the `WHERE` clause twice, and I don't like that. I'd ideally want to see the `WHERE` clause only once. I've tried to simplify this down, and I got this, but the problem is that it returns more than one row:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN
            CASE
                WHEN C.CONTENTS = 'N' THEN 'X'
                WHEN C.CONTENTS = ' ' THEN 'X'
                WHEN C.CONTENTS = '' THEN 'X'
                ELSE '*'
            END
        ELSE '_'
    END AS 'RESULT'
FROM TABLE C
WHERE
    USERID = '123456789' AND
    DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')
GROUP BY C.CONTENTS
```

I believe windowing functions may help me, but I'm having a lot of trouble coming up with one for this scenario. Is it possible to have a query that does not repeat the `WHERE` clause that can get the results I would prefer, returning only one result regardless of number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of what rslemos posted earlier, I was able to find a solution that fit my requirements, and one that remains easy to read and understand.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(
            CASE
                WHEN CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ') THEN 1
                ELSE NULL 
            END) > 0 THEN '*'
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'X'
        ELSE '_'
    END AS 'RESULT'
FROM TABLE
WHERE USERID = '123456789'
AND DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')
```

I'm still a little unsure on this one, since I'm using `COUNT(*)`, but this so far has passed the tests I needed it to pass.

Comment: Consider the case where an USERID will have not a single row with `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')`. Then the query from OP will return '_', but this answer's proposal will return nothing.

Comment: Actually, when I tested, a USERID without a row with `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')` returned `_`. This is what I want to occur. A non-existent USERID also returns `_`, not quite intended, but I can guarantee prior to this query being run that USERID will exist (due to previous validation)

Comment: how can it be? `WHERE USERID = '123456789' AND DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')` kills every row without `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')`; and since that the USERID given has no row with it, the `SELECT` returns nothing. I cannot return anything other than nothing.

Comment: When I do `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERID='123456789'`, if that USERID doesn't match any rows, I get nothing. But when I run it through the first query in this post, I get `_` back. I believe the `CASE` will still evaluate regardless, and end up at the `ELSE '_'`

Comment: Oh, I thought you ought to remove that IF ... THEN ... ELSE. At least that is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `CASE WHEN ... END` inside the `COUNT` (it doesn't count NULL items), and grouping by `USERID`:

```
SELECT USERID, CASE WHEN STAR > 0 THEN '*' WHEN X > 0 THEN 'X' ELSE '_' END
FROM (
    SELECT USERID, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3') AND CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS STAR,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS X
     FROM TABLE
     GROUP BY USERID
     ) AS x
WHERE USERID = '123456789'
```

I don't have an SQL Server here right now, so I'm not sure it could be made it all together, without the anonymous view. You could give it a try:

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN COUNT(
                CASE WHEN
                        DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')
                    AND CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ') THEN 1
                    ELSE NULL 
                END) > 0 THEN '*'
            WHEN COUNT(
                CASE WHEN
                        DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3') THEN 1
                    ELSE NULL
                END) > 0 THEN 'X'
            ELSE '_'
        END
FROM TABLE
WHERE USERID = '123456789'
```

**EDIT**

To remove the duplicate `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1'...)` (from the first snippet):

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN COUNT_DESCRIPTION > 0 AND COUNT_CONTENTS > 0 THEN '*'
            WHEN COUNT_DESCRIPTION > 0 THEN 'X'
            ELSE '_'
        END
FROM (
    SELECT  USERID, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS COUNT_DESCRIPTION,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS COUNT_CONTENTS
    FROM    TABLE
    GROUP BY USERID
) AS x
WHERE   USERID = '123456789'
```

This will not work, though, in the case of some USERID having rows with `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')` and without `CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ')` (i.e., `CONTENTS IN ('N','',' ')`), and **other** rows with `CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ')` and without `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')`. For such USERID, the last query will return '*', but in fact should return 'X' (the set of rows with `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')` and the set of rows with `CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ')` are disjoint).

**EDIT 2**
(a new proposal based on the above, hopefully working)

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN COUNT(DESCRIPTION_PREDICATE) > 0 AND COUNT(CONTENTS_PREDICATE) > 0 THEN '*'
            WHEN COUNT(CONTENTS_PREDICATE) > 0 THEN 'X'
            ELSE '_'
        END
FROM (
    SELECT  USERID, 
        CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS DESCRIPTION_PREDICATE,
        CASE WHEN CONTENTS NOT IN ('N','',' ') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CONTENTS_PREDICATE
    FROM    TABLE
) AS x
WHERE   USERID = '123456789'
GROUP BY USERID
```

Comment: The first one works, which is great, but it repeats the `DESCRIPTION IN ('D1','D2','D3')`. I used filler names for the sake of simplicity in this post, but in the actual query the condition is quite enormous, so I'd like to avoid that if at all possible. This looks to be the right direction to start, though.

Comment: I built off this in an answer I posted. Still not 100% sure on it, but it's working for my purposes at the moment. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've posted an edit for your comment. Give it a try. I've seen your answer; to my reckon it will fail in some corner cases, which I can't elaborate right now (I'll do it later).

Comment: It indeed works, though I'm concerned about what would happen when I start adding conditions. I probably should have specified that `DESCRIPTION` and `USERID` are not the only conditions--there will be many more. I do like separating `COUNT_DESCRIPTION` and `COUNT_CONTENTS` a lot though.

Comment: I did more testing, the edit will not work. It doesn't have a link between `CONTENTS` and `DESCRIPTION` when generating `COUNT_CONTENTS`. The solution to that... would be to duplicate the `DESCRIPTION` clause again. Currently, the second option (with `DESCRIPTION` moved to the `WHERE` to avoid duplication) is the one that works, though I'd like to hear about the corner cases where what I wrote would fail first.

Comment: @MariM, yes, as I said, I was afraid that a disjoint set would spoil the query. I'll explain in another edit.

Comment: @MariM, I'm afraid you have a deeper modelling problem in your database layout. Perhaps you should ask (in another question, not this one) for advice, giving more detail about your data.